# Evalute the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_0^4x^2d([x^2])$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, riemann-integration

Evalute the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. (Here $x\mapsto [x]$ denotes the greatest integer functión).

$$\int_0^4x^2d([x^2])$$

My approach:

By integration by parts we have that:  $$\int_0^4x^2d([x^2])=(4^2)([4^2])-\int_0^4[x^2]d(x^2) = (16)(15)-\int_0^4[x^2]d(x^2)$$ because $x^2$ is differtiable at $[0,4]$ can rewrite it like a Riemann integral: $$\int_0^4[x^2]d(x^2)= \int_0^4[t^2]2tdt$$
I´m kind of confused on how to evaluate $\int_0^4[t^2]2tdt$. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Hint: Break it into integrals depending on the value of $[t^{2}]$.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was trying but for example, at $[1,2]$  the value of $[t^2] $ is between $1$ and $3$. So what division of $[0,4]$ would you recommend?

Comment: By the substitution $u=x^2$, we have $$\int_{0}^{4}x^2\,\mathrm{d}\lfloor x^2\rfloor=\int_{0}^{16}u\,\mathrm{d}\lfloor u\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{16}k=\frac{16\cdot17}{2}.$$